# Can the parameters for a plot be saved in a passable variable in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, parameter-passing, random-walk

In the following expample I would like to assign the arguments passed to the plot in an appropriate datatype. Let his name be "plotargument". How do I assign plotargument correctly so I am able to get the same result from `df.plot(plotargument)` as from 
`df.plot(x='Timestep', y='Position', figsize=(14,7),fontsize=15,grid=True)`.

An example usecase is to be found below:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import random

series=[0]
for x in range(0,2000):
    series.append(series[x]+1) if random()<0.5 else series.append(series[x]-1) 
df= pd.DataFrame({'Timestep' :[x * 200 for x in range(0,2001)], 'Position': series })

df.plot(x='Timestep', y='Position', figsize=(14,7),fontsize=15,grid=True)
```

Comment: One option would be to have it as a dict, then unpack it, eg: `plotargument = dict(x='Timestep', y='Position', figsize=(14,7),fontsize=15,grid=True)`... then use it as `df.plot(**plotargument)`...

Comment: This should have been posted as an answer rather than a comment

Comment: @NicolasGervais not necessarily... it's still ambiguous as to what "safe the arguments passed to the plot" means - this was just a guess and a suggested attempt to make... Kind of hoping Dr.Ario elaborates on whether the comment above is something  they can use or whether they were thinking something else... (eg: save to disk or database or maybe save the arguments *after* the plot has already been made... etc...)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jon.
Your comment answers my question, especially with the doublestar syntax for passing the argument. I edited the question to remove the ambiguous part (hopefully).

Comment: Ah you're right. Well your answer was excellent if ever that's what OP needed